# Show that all $3$-sylow subgroups of $S_4$ are conjugate.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Show that all $3$-sylow subgroups in $S_4$  are conjugate.
Number of $3$-sylow subgroup is $(1+3k)$ s.t $8|(1+3k)$ . . . so number of $3$-sylow subgroup is either $1$ or $4$.

Since symmetric group $S_n$ ($n>3$) does not contain proper normal subgroup. So number of $3$-sylow subgroup is must be $4$.

Now what do I do to solve this problem?

Comment: The number of $3$-sylow subgroups is not relevant. Since $3^2\nmid 4!$, all $3$-sylow subgroups have order $3$, hence are cyclic, and since $4<3+3$ they must be generated by $3$-cycles. All $3$-cycles are conjugate.

Comment: Note that by the Sylow Theorems, all Sylow-$p$ subgroups (for a fixed prime $p$) are conjugate. That is, the action of the group $G$ on $\text{Syl}_{p}(G)$ by conjugation is transitive.

Comment: @arctictern What has 4 < 3 + 3 got to do with it being generated by 3-cycles?

Comment: $4<3+3$ implies the only elements of $S_4$ of order three are $3$-cycles (as opposed to products of multiple disjoint $3$-cycles).

Answer (score 1):

*As @arctictern put in a comment . . .*

Because $3^2\nmid 4!$, every $3$-sylow subgroup  has order $3$, so they must be cyclic. But $4<3+3$, so they must be generated by $3$-cycles. All $3$-cycles are conjugate.